# Parse JSON data and put them into a gridview

Tags: android, json, android-arrayadapter, android-gridview

I'm developing an application in which I have to parse `JSON` data and have to put them in custom `gridview`. Here is what it should look like.

[image: How to display the gridview?]

So far I have parsed my JSON data in asynctask and getting those values. Here is my code:

```
private class getRedeemData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdia = new ProgressDialog(AllPerksActivity.this);
        pdia.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pdia.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,
                HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
                "MY API HERE..!!");

        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        try {
            post.setEntity(new StringEntity("client_id=" + client_id + "&"
                    + "client_secret=" + clientSecretKey, HTTP.UTF_8));

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
            int i = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            System.out.println("HTTP Post status AllPerk Redeemption API: "
                    + i);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));

            // SB to make a string out of the inputstream
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();

            // the json string is stored here
            String result = sb.toString();
            System.out.println("Result Body: " + result);
            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        JSONObject jObject;
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(result);

            JSONArray jSearchData = jObject.getJSONArray("rewards");

            for (int i = 0; i < jSearchData.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject objJson = jSearchData.getJSONObject(i);

                String rewardID = objJson.getString("rewardID");
                String rewardType = objJson.getString("rewardType");
                String rewardTitle = objJson.getString("rewardTitle");

                System.out.println("Reward ID: " + rewardID);
                System.out.println("Reward Type: " + rewardType);
                System.out.println("Reward Tittle: " + rewardTitle);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        pdia.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Here is my XML for Gridview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/grid"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:numColumns="2"
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
</GridView>
```

Can some one tell my how to use adapter for this problem.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you got any error ?

Comment: No. just wanted to ask how to implement the stuff after parsing and all the things.

Comment: have you not yet created an Adapter? if so follow the android docs http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: @LochanaRagupathy No I don't have any adapter till now.

Comment: just try to implement it with the help of above example

Comment: Not related, but you should also use GSON to parse your data, you will not need to handwrite so much of parsing logic then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You save the JSON data in some array and then

```
gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));
```

Refer to this link for Gridview with custom adapter

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

Answer (score 0):

After parsing the JSON data store the data in a collection (an ArrayList will do), create an adapter and bind it with your GridView using `setAdapter` method of the grid view

Check the [developer docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

Can do easily. 
Check the reference [Android gridview using json data](http://devsbucket.com/android/json-object-using-gridview-adnroid/)